# How to go to main screen of mobile from app when on home page(Dashboard) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to go to home screen on back pressed, but it goes to previous Activity, I tried `onWillScope()`, does anybody know the solution to this.

What I want to achieve?
On back pressed => go to home screen and not on previous activity of app.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your `onWillPop` callback.

```
SystemNavigator.pop();
```

---

```
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () {
    SystemNavigator.pop(); // use this
    return Future.value(false); // return false
  },
  child: ...,
)
```

Comment: I don't want to redirect to the main page , I want the app closed on back pressed.

Comment: But last line of our post says `On back pressed => go to home screen`

Comment: Yea so home screen is where all inbuilt apps are there(when app closes and you're back to your home screen, I meant this way)